# How to export lines from other file into current shell

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, eval

I have this content in a file called `foo.env`:

```
foo=bar
```

and then I want to read that file and export the lines to the shell:

```
for line in $(cat ./foo.env); do
 eval export $line
done
```

but when I run

```
echo $foo
```

the variable is empty..what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unmodified code

```
for line in $(cat ./foo.env); do
 eval export $line
done
echo $foo
```

if put into a file and executed with sh or bash, does exactly what you request. Perhaps you ran `echo $foo` in a different shell?

Note, however, that POSIX shell defines a builtin for this case specifically:

```
. ./foo.env
echo $foo
```